# Выведите символ и длину последовательности. Если таких несколько – выведите последнюю

Tags: python

> Дана строка s. Выведите символ и длину последовательности. Если таких несколько – выведите последнюю.
> Данные на вход и какие должны получиться
>
> Sample Input:
>
> ```
> aaabbccccaaaab
> ```
>
> Sample Output:
>
> ```
> a
> 4
> ```

вот мой код, я не знаю как вывести именно последнюю подстроку, если таких несколько

```
s=input()
c=[0,0]
l=[s[0],s[0]]
for i in s:
   if i==l[1]:
      c[1]+=1
      if c[1]>c[0]:
         c[0]=c[1]
         l[0]=l[1]
   else:
      c[1]=1
      l[1]=i
print(c[0],l[0])
```

Comment: И что же вы от нас хотите? Вы не написали.

Comment: *«Выведите символ...»* - Какой символ? Первый в строке?

Comment: @MarianD, судя по сэмплу, нужно вывести самую длинную последовательность одинаковых символов. Если нашлось несколько равнодлинных последовательностей, вывести последнюю

Comment: Добавляйте в результирующий список словарь/кортеж/список вида `символ-количество повторений`. Если нашелся символ с бОльшим количеством повторений, обновите результирующий список, если с таким же количеством повторений - добавьте в конец списка. Таким образом, при одинаковом количестве повторений последний элемент списка будет ответом.

Comment: Если хотите посмотреть другие возможные варианты решения поиска последовательность в строке, посмотрите [данный](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664150/counting-longest-occurrence-of-repeated-sequence-in-python) топик.

Comment: @Dmitry, красиво от вас, что вы мне ответили, что **вы думаете**, но я хотел **привлечь автора вопроса к точной формулировке его задания.**